# Correct way to use "enumitem" (or its alternatives) for itemize in Latex Beamer

Tags: latex, tex, beamer

I'm trying to customize my `itemize` list in a Beamer slide using the `noitemsep` and `topsep` settings available in the `enumitem` package. However, using `enumitem` with Beamer causes the bullet points to disappear (images attached below). I also came to know that `enumitem` isn't really compatible with Beamer, and should not be used alongside the `enumerate` package, but I can't figure out what alternatives are available for my use case.

When I don't use `enumitem`

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Apples
        \item Oranges
        \item Bananas
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Output (contains bullet points):

[image]

When I use `enumitem`:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
        \item Apples
        \item Oranges
        \item Bananas
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Output (the bullets have disappeared):

[image]

Any hints regarding what settings I should use with `enumitem` when using Beamer, or what other alternative packages I can use (which is more compatible with Beamer) which can fulfill my objective, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `enumitem` with beamer, it is not compatible.

You can adjust the spacing in various ways, either locally or globally.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
text
    \vskip-1ex
    \begin{itemize}
    \addtolength{\itemsep}{-1ex}
        \item Apples
        \item Oranges
        \item Bananas
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\itemize}
  {\def\makelabel}
  {%
    \addtolength{\itemsep}{-1ex}%
    \def\makelabel%
  }
  {}
  {}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\vskip-1ex}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
text
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Apples
        \item Oranges
        \item Bananas
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```